# How to scroll in video spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, video-streaming

I have built a dummy video streaming application in spring boot,I have noticed that i cant skip to another frame or to a certain time in a video.
Here is my code to read videoFile

```
public byte[] getVideo() throws IOException {


        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        inputStream.read(bytes);
        return bytes;
    }
```

and this is my what my video controller returns

```
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
                .header("Content-Type","video/mp4")
                .header("Content-length",String.valueOf(streamingService.file.length()))
                .body(streamingService.getVideo());
```

note i am not using any frontend

Comment: You don't add header `Accept-Ranges: bytes`, so the browsers think the server doesn't support it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some experimentation, I found that the browser (Chrome) made another GET request to a certain byte range, and my `getVideo()` method was not well-written enough to accept the byte range and return the required byte range.

After rewriting my `VideoStreamingService,` the problem was solved for Chrome.

Here is my rewritten code for `getVideo()`:

```
byte[] data;
        Long fileSize = file.length();
        String[] ranges = range.split("-");
        rangeStart = Long.parseLong(ranges[0].substring(6));
        if (ranges.length > 1) {
            rangeEnd = Long.parseLong(ranges[1]);
        } else {
            rangeEnd = fileSize - 1;
        }
        if (fileSize < rangeEnd) {
            rangeEnd = fileSize - 1;
        }
        contentLength = String.valueOf((rangeEnd - rangeStart) + 1);
       data = readByteRange( rangeStart, rangeEnd);
       return  data;
```

`readRangeByte()` method so I can read data appropriately:

```
public byte[] readByteRange(long start, long end) throws IOException {
        try (InputStream inputStream = (Files.newInputStream(Path.of(videoFileName)));
             ByteArrayOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            byte[] data = new byte[128];
            int nRead;
            while ((nRead = inputStream.read(data, 0, data.length)) != -1) {
                bufferedOutputStream.write(data, 0, nRead);
            }
            bufferedOutputStream.flush();
            byte[] result = new byte[(int) (end - start) + 1];
            System.arraycopy(bufferedOutputStream.toByteArray(), (int) start, result, 0, result.length);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

and my controller class code:

```
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> video(@RequestHeader(value = "Range",required = false) String range) throws IOException {
        if (range == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK)
                    .header("Content-Type", "video/mp4")
                    .header("Content-Length", String.valueOf(streamingService.file.length()))
                    .body(streamingService.readByteRange(streamingService.getRangeStart(),streamingService.file.length()-1));
        }
        byte[] data = streamingService.getVideo(range);

        return  ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.PARTIAL_CONTENT)
                .header("Content-Type", "video/mp4")
                .header("Accept-Ranges", "bytes")
                .header("Content-Length", streamingService.getContentLength())
                .header("Content-Range", "bytes" + " " + streamingService.getRangeStart() + "-" + streamingService.getRangeEnd() + "/" + streamingService.file.length())
                .body(data);
```

After @Andreas suggestion the code works very well with both the browsers

Comment: When `range == null`, which it will be when you first start viewing the video, you don't add header `Accept-Ranges: bytes`, so the browsers think the server doesn't support it.

Comment: Oh thanks this works with firefox now but still it buffers for a few seconds in both the browsers