# How does FileUrlResources works?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

So am building an dummy video streaming application using java and spring boot.
when i am trying to video streaming without using [FileUrlResources](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE_to_5.0.4.RELEASE/Spring%20Framework%205.0.4.RELEASE/org/springframework/core/io/FileUrlResource.html) and doing it manually ([link to the code am using](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67549178/9158405)) i am able to go a specific time in video but just in chrome(with a side effect it buffers before going to specific time in video) but in Firefox i cant go to specific point in video.

But when i am using FileUrlResources its works great in both the browsers with no side effect and i cant figure out what its doing.

In ResponseEntity i am returning just FileUrlResources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works with [`FileUrlResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/FileUrlResource.html), because [`readableChannel()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/AbstractFileResolvingResource.html#readableChannel--) returns a [`SeekableByteChannel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SeekableByteChannel.html), so the logic processing the `FileUrlResource` on the server fully implements the HTTP `Range` headers.

Comment: i just checked readableChannel its return type is ReadableByteChannel.

Comment: @klaus Yes, but [**File**UrlResource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.9.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/FileUrlResource.html) returns a [**File**Channel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html), which implements [SeekableByteChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SeekableByteChannel.html).

Comment: oh i see thank you.looks like i need to do some googling to have ability to randomly seek the required byte range